# handle all forms for one resource on the same page (php)

Tags: php

currently I am doing CRUD task for a resource "events" and for each task I have one page that the form for that task submits to (i.e events/create.php, events/read.php, events/update.php, events/delete.php). I would like to instead handle all of this one one page (sort of like with Ruby on Rails when there is an EventsController with index, show, put, and delete methods). I would not like to use a framework. How can I do this in raw php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is achieved by two things.

Firstly, direct all traffic to this page by manipulating your server configuration. In the case of Apache, that is most often done by placing a `.htaccess` file in the webroot of your project with something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php [L]
```

Which will direct all traffic to an `index.php`.

Secondly, your PHP script must be capable of translating every request into something meaningful by capturing at minimum the request URI, method and body.

Because you are not interested in using a framework, you'll have your work cut out for you. As a start, you should look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and capturing the raw request body with something like:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Once you have this data you have to decide how you want to trigger the appropriate functions in your script based on the above, which involves parsing the URL, checking the request content-type header to decide how to parse the input and so on.

If you decide this is all too much work given there are dozens of premade solutions, you should [look at FastRoute which is a very popular library](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) that covers everything I've written here.